# How to solve $\sin x \cos y - \sin u \cos v= a$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

Please help me to solve this problem.

If $x\in[0,\pi]$, $y\in[0,2\pi]$, $u\in[0,\pi]$, and $a\in[-2,2]$ are given, how to find $v\in[0,2\pi]$?

Is this correct $v=\cos^{-1}(\frac{\sin x \cos y-a}{\sin u})$?

Only for certain values of $x,y,u,$ and $a$, I am getting a real $v$. Most of the time I get complex values.

Thanks

Comment: That should give you one solution (if any solutions exist depending on the value of $a$). You will also need to consider the solutions at $2\pi$ minus whatever the above evaluates to. This all assumes of course that $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As soon as the argument to $\cos^{-1}$ leaves the domain $[-1,1]$ then the answers will be complex.

Comment: But the above equation returns a complex value of $v$ for certain value of $x,y,u$, and $a$ .

Comment: but the solution depends on $a$?